# Why is a function satisfying a throwing requirement without throwing?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, throw

```
protocol Throwing {
    func x() throws
}


class C : Throwing{
    func x(){
        print("not throwing") // no errors!
    }
}
```

Why isn't the compiler not throwing any errors? Is this by design or this is a bug?

Comment: A matt demonstrates, it's by design – a function that never throws can satisfy the requirement of a function that *might* throw (bear in mind that marking a function with `throws` doesn't enforce that the function can actually throw an error). The inverse however wouldn't be sound, e.g attempting to use a function that might throw to satisfy the requirement of a function that never throws.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for the same reason that this compiles:

```
class A {
    func x() throws {}
}
class B:A {
    override func x() {}
}
```

And this:

```
func f() {}
func yoho (_ f : () throws -> Void) {}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    yoho(f)
}
```

And this:

```
func f() {}
var fun : (() throws -> Void)!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.fun = f
}
```

Comment: It's just the nature of covariance of functions. You can always provide a nonthrower where a thrower is expected. But not the other way around.

Comment: Good article here: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html He doesn’t address throws specifically but the principle is the same: a simple function embraces a throwing function just as a supertype parameter embraces a subtype parameter.